# Rails: How to declare an optional one-to-one association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations, one-to-many

I am new to rails, and was not sure how to set the following up.

I have Users, Invitations and Pictures models. Each user my invite other users to view a particular picture. The user sends an invitation to the other user; the invitation may be linked to a particular picture, or may not be linked to one at all.

My problem was I was not sure how to associate an optional relation between the invitation and the picture.

I have:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invitation
end
```

However, when I try invitation.picture, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: @user.getsInvited invitation
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: picture.invitation_id: SELECT  "picture".* FROM "picture"  WHERE "picture"."invitation_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Probably I need to add the column invitation to the picture model, however, is this necessary - sending a picture may be optional in the invitation. Also, if I did have a single invitation_id column in picture, what happens if the same picture is shared between various invitations?

I.e. each invitation may have a single picture associated to it and other invitations may have the same picture associated to them. I didnt want the picture to be "aware" of the invitations, but maybe I have to by creating a many-to-many relation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invitation is the one that should know what it is attached to:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture # means invitation model has a picture_id column
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations
end
```

Comment: This way an invitation have an optional picture (just don't set the `picture_id` field ;))